# Will we be taxed on gift money we received for a down payment on a house?

Tags: income-tax, gifts

My boyfriend and I bought a house over the summer and received money as a gift to help with down payment. His mom gave $10000 and my dad gave $14000. we later received a $5000 house warming gift from his grandparents. will we be taxed on receiving these gifts?

Comment: In the US, gift _givers_ may be subject to tax, not gift _receivers_. And $14K is the limit for one individual to another, so they should be fine.

Comment: As a side note, make sure that _both_ of you are on the title _and_ mortgage, and that there's an agreement in writing as to how much of the house each of you owns. There are many questions dealing with breakup situations with a shared house involved.

Comment: You'd better be getting them all some nice Christmas/Hanukkah/Eid/whatever gifts ;)

Comment: Which country are you in?